# Jquery function to change id name continues to run on other pages even thouigh i don't want it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This behavior is happening on a intranet website structured for computer based training. I am using a function to change "id" name of a div using `jquery` on the fly on a single page.

```
$('#frameTextBg').attr('id','frameTextBg-horz');
```

It works fine. The problem is that when I navigate to another page, this functions continues to run and any page with div name `#frameTextBg` is being renamed to `frameTextBg-horz`.

I navigate to other pages using `jquery` to load pages inside a div. Note `"var NextPage"` is declared in each page by the authoring programs html export:

```
function NextPage() {
   $('#content').load(nextPage) 
};
```

How can I stop this function from running on other pages?

Thanks in advance.

Mark

Here are portions of the html markup relevant to the "outside" container that will load each page inside a div named `#content`.

```
...
<body class="mainBody" onLoad="resizeCBT();">
    <div id="container">
        <div id='content'></div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p id="footerP">LessonName</p>
            <div id="footerPG">00 of 00</div>
            <div id="footerNav"></div>
            <div id="footerID" style="display:block" ></div>
        <div id="control" name="control"><div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#content').load("Menu-0.htm"); 

$( "#control" ).load( "interface/control.htm #select1" );

document.getElementById('control').style.display="none";

</script>
</body>
...
```

Next are portions of the markup for a single page that runs the function to rename the id:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  var frame_id = 95675
  var graphic_1 = "20.png"
  var graphic_2 = ""
  var nextPage = "a.htm"
  var prevPage = "c.htm"
  var thisPage = "b.htm"
  var menuTitle = ""
  var frameTitle = "title"
  var sequence = 20
  var totalFrames = 26
  var manifestName = "No_Flash"
  var instructText = ""
  var audioFilename = ""

function runAfterPgLoad()   {
$('#frameTextBg').attr('id','frameTextBg-off');
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="header1"><h1 id="header1t">headerOne</h1></div>
    <div id="header2"><h1 id="header2t">HeaderTwo</h1></div>
    <div id="header3"></div>
</div>

<div id="GRAPHIC"><img src="20.png"></div>
<div id="TEXT" class="text">Text here.</div>

<div id="frameTextBg"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function NextPage() {
    $('#content').load(nextPage) 
};

function PrevPage() {
    $('#content').load(prevPage)
};


document.getElementById('footerID').innerHTML = frame_id;
document.getElementById('footerPG').innerHTML = sequence + " of " + totalFrames;

if (typeof runAfterPgLoad == 'function') { 
  runAfterPgLoad(); 
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Other pages DO NOT have the function:

```
function runAfterPgLoad()   {
$('#frameTextBg').attr('id','frameTextBg-off');
}
```

Note that some markup has been omitted because this material cannot be disclosed. Sorry if I accidentally cut off any relevant markup.

Comment: You'll have to post more code. How is that first sample of code invoked?

Comment: it depends on where and how you're calling this, more code would help

Comment: You need to find how you can identify that page, and use that information to decide whether or not to change the id, or that script belongs ONLY on that page. Not enough info given.

Comment: I added some code to the original post. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using ajax to replace PARTS of your page. since you're not reloading the entire page, or using a normal "click to go to next page" system, that function will keep working until you tell it to stop, e.g.

```
var stop_it_already = false;
if (!stop_it_already) {
    $('#frameTextBg').attr('id','frameTextBg-horz');
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying but you do understand that the function is running on a "internally" loaded page (ex: page_20.htm) not the outside page (index.htm); and it is on this internally loaded page that I modifying PARTS. I guess I kind of assumed when a new page is loaded (internally), it would "stop" the function on its own since the page that originally loaded the function has been replaced by a new page. Make sense? Sorry if I'm a bit of a newbie. I posted some markup as other users requested. In any case thank you for your time and response.

Comment: so whatever you're `.load()`ing is what contains the function? you're basically snipping off a branch of the DOM tree and replacing it with new html, which will act as if that part of the page  had just had its reload button clicked. that means any code in that section will also be re-executed.

Comment: Yes..what ever I'm loading will contain or not the function. I guess I just thought when I loaded a new page the divs in that page would not be renamed by the function that ran earlier....so much to learn.

Comment: then you still need a sentinel that the code can check for to NOT run if need be.

Comment: is it conceivable to have the function run and then stop or remove itself?...so that when the next page is loaded it starts fresh....without any thing carried over....

Comment: not really, because even if it removed itself from the snippet you loaded right now, it'd be there again in the NEXT snippet that gets loaded.

Comment: is .one() or .unbind() anything I should consider? I haven't read up on them....yet...

Comment: also pointless. remember - you're physically deleting a chunk of your page and replacing it with another chunk. since your misbehaving JS code is hardcoded into that chunk, removing it from the currently load page will just make it appear again when you replace the chunk. that's why you need the external sentinel (e.g. variable) that your bad code can test for for.

Comment: or maybe I can just run a function to reset things to "default" when loaded and then apply the modification if needed...just seems messy...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a definitive answer, because I'm still unclear about how exactly `NextPage` gets called.

You should never have different HTML elements with the same `id`. Since it's not something you're meant to do, I'm not even sure the specification for HTML says what should happen, so your page may behave differently on different browsers. Does `$('#frameTextBg')` represent all `frameTextBg` elements? Or does the browser only let it be one element and, if so, which one?

I used to work on a project which involved embedding lots of not-quite-identical copies of a website in another website. We had to change all the `id` attributes to CSS classes. Then, assuming all the `frameTextBg` elements are in different sections of the website, we could write `$('.section-1 .frameTextBg')`, `$('.section-2 .frameTextBg')`, etc.

> Note `"var NextPage"` is declared in each page by the authoring programs html export

My client-side javascript is a little rusty, but I *think* that any declaration not inside a function definition just goes in the global scope anyway. This could cause problems with the latest copy of `NextPage` running instead of an earlier one. (But I can't tell because I don't see where `NextPage` is called from.)

You say you're reloading part of the page. Do you really need to reload the part with the `<script>` element?

Comment: Thank you for your time and response. The var NextPage is declared as you can see in the second window with markup above.

Comment: In this scenario a index.htm loads pages inside a div using jquery. The div #frameTextBg will be exclusive to each page loaded and will appear only once per page. Since some flexibility in layout is needed regarding its appearance (size, location, etc) we are consideration renaming the id on the fly .....but without the "redeclaring" the function parameters or using some checking method the function keeps running as other pages are loaded.....

Another option may be to simply alter the css for #frameTextBg using a onload event.

Comment: `NextPage` is a function, but it's not declared inside a function block so I think it's declared globally. How can elements be on different pages if they're inside the same div? I still don't see why you're renaming it - for changing layout, adding/removing CSS classes would be more standard. But tell me this: What causes `NextPage` to run? It sounds to me like you've got it running repeatedly when you only need to run it once per page load.

Comment: NextPage is called from the navigation bar-next page button in the index.htm ( outer container) which is not visible in the markup i posted above (sorry). You are right that I shoukd consider altering the css rather than rename the id. Thanks for your input.

Comment: If `NextPage` is called as a click handler, then you can: (1) remove the class attribute from all "page" elements; (2) use the click event to get the button element; (3) find the "page" you want to navigate to; and (4) add the class attribute. I still don't really have enough information to know how (3) might work.